# GPIO in device tree

Tags: arm, embedded, gpio

My board has 3 GPIOs, namely `gpio0`, `gpio1` and `gpio2`. Each of them have 32 pins. They were declared in device tree as below:

```
    gpio@ff708000 {  
                   #address-cells = <1>;  
                   #size-cells = <0>;  
                   compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio";  
                   reg = <0xff708000 0x1000>;  
                   clocks = <&per_base_clk>;  
                   status = "disabled";  

                   gpio0: gpio-controller@0 {
                           compatible = "snps,dw-apb-gpio-port";
                           gpio-controller;
                           #gpio-cells = <2>;
                           snps,nr-gpios = <29>;
                           reg = <0>;
                           interrupt-controller;
                           #interrupt-cells = <2>;
                           interrupts = <0 164 4>;
                   };
           };
```

I'm interested in this line: `interrupts = <0 164 4>;`.

1. What does 164 mean?
2. What is its relation with IRQ number?
3. Since it has 32 pins, how does the processor know the interrupt is coming from which pin since it only has one interrupt number, 164?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you using Linux? The device tree is a feature of newer...3.0 kernels, yes? Just wondering...don't think I have an answer for you. :|

Comment: Ya, I'm using Linux. You're right, device tree is a new feature which was introduced in kernel 3.x

Comment: This question is about operating system software and has nothing to do with the electrical design of the processor. It would probably get a better response on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or the more-specific [Unix/Linux.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).